# Javascript function getting called only on event!

Tags: javascript, opensocial

I have a javascript function, I want it to be called programatically on init and later onClick event but its not getting called programatically but works ok with onClick.

The example would be:

```
function init() {
  a(); 
}
```

`init()` is called on initialization which should call `a()` but thats not happening!

Comment: There's not really enough to go on here.  The code for `function a()` might be more helpful, as well as any debugging/error messages you're receiving.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example working 100 %

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>sdasddss</title>


    <script type="text/javascript">
  function init(){
alert("I'm calling afunction()");
afunction();
}

function afunction(){
alert("I was called successfuly");
}

window.onload = init;
  </script>

</head>

<body>

My body

</body>
</html>
```